# Сервер с async overlapped i/o на с#

Tags: c#, сокет

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом из обычного асинхронного сервера можно сделать асинхронный сервер с перекрытием? От чего необходимо отталкиваться и какие значимые функции использовать?

P.S. Если нужно, могу предоставить код асинхронного сервера.

Comment: @wao138: А что такое «с перекрытием»? И да, наверное, лучше покажите какую-нибудь центральную часть существующего кода (но не весь, ладно? читать большую простыню никому не захочется) и скажите, что с ней не так.

Comment: @VladD, все с обычной асинхронной хорошо, но теперь просто нужно добавить к ней перекрытие (сам пока особо не понимаю, что это такое). За основу взят этот код http://hashcode.ru/questions/394883/socket-%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81

Comment: @wao138: И я не понимаю :( Подождём, может, кто-то подскажет.

Comment: @VladD, знаю лишь, что на С++ это как-то с помощью структуры overlapped реализуется

Comment: Были тут [подобные темы](http://hashcode.ru/questions/385042).

Насколько понимаю, речь идет об асинхронном вводе-выводе в винде, т.е. инициируем операцию IO и занимаемся чем-то еще, а потом ловим событие о завершении этой операции. 

Вот [тут](http://www.e-reading.link/chapter.php/141823/479/Hart_-_Sistemnoe_programmirovanie_v_srede_Windows.html) кое-какой обзор таких методов IO.

--

@wao138, Вы уверены, что на самом деле что-то выиграете с таким подходом?

Answer (score 3):

Если вы используете .NET 4.5 и выше, Винда у вас Виста и выше, то просто используйте асинхронные варианты всех используемых вами методов (возвращают `Task`/`Task<T>` и имеют имена XxxAsync) -- они все внутри "правильным" образом обращаются к IO. Понятно, что все эти методы использовать нужно правильно -- почитайте базовые статьи по async/await, коих в Интернете достаточно.